# Using Two HTML for Single component in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4. Is it is possible to use two html file for single component? If yes, can any one tell me how.

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit more? How should the two HTML files get merged? Are you trying to embed one html in the other?

Comment: No, if you would like to use 2 html templates then you must use 2 different components.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: In registration i have two section. Basic information and  contact information. Once i m done with Basic information, I will click next button it should navigate to contact information. Both functionality are in same component

Comment: create a new component and use that as a child view

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you cannot use two `*.html` files for a single component.

If there is concept of master page & content page then I can suggest you something

Comment: In registration i have two section. Basic information and contact information. Once i m done with Basic information, I will click next button it should navigate to contact information. Both functionality are in same component

Comment: then you can use tabbed menu so from that you can navigate from  one from to another for easily .or else you can use two components

Comment: if you need i cant help you for that , so let me know

Answer (score 1):

Even if you find a tricky way to do so, it will be an anti pattern, meaning that you will face bigger trouble as the application grows.

I recommend you to create two components and localize the common logic in a service. Read more about services at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_services.htm

Or you can create a new component and use a child view as pointed out by @Muthu

Answer (score 0):

I realize this Angular 2+ post is over a year old, but I hope this helps someone. There is really a *Trick* to creating components with two or more html files. You'd have multiple @components each followed by classes. This could be used for modal popups or something I guess.

**Same file**:

```
import { Component, ... } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'first-component',
    templateUrl: './first.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss'],
})
export classFirstComponent {

   constructor() {}
   ... Doing something here.

}

@Component({
    selector: 'second-page',
    templateUrl: './second-page.html',
})

export class SecondPage {

   constructor() {}
   ... Doing something here.
}
```